# Horizontal Align Search Bar and Button

Tags: html, css, css-position, line-breaks

I was really struggling with this issue...

I've got 6 linear buttons as a navigation and a search bar after them. All I need to keep them on the same like and make a search bar liquid. But the search bar always breaks a line.

I've tried so many ways to fix it. I know some solutions as using "cacl" or wrap them inside a table but I need some normal way to do it and make a responsive my search bar.

I would be really glad if someone will explain to me what is wrong.

Thank you.

```
    <div class="navigation">          
                <button id="navigation-buttons">Sales</button>
                <button id="navigation-buttons">HR</button>
                <button id="navigation-buttons">OVP</button>

            <form action="#" method="get" class="search-box">
                <input type="search" />
            </form>
    </div>
<style>
    input {

    display: inline; 
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;

    }

    .search-box {

    display: inline;

    }

    div.navigation { 

    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;

    }

    button#navigation-buttons {

    background-color: #000099;
    border: 0px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to display all in same row, and search bar at end of buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` this class `div.navigation`

```
div.navigation {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying all in the same line, use the following:

```
.search-box {
  display: inline;    
}
```

And if you want to keep it always in the same line, even when the screen size is changed, then also use the code provided by Lalji Tadhani in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace style sheet like below..

input {

```
display: inline; 
height: 31px;
width: 100%;

}

.search-box {

display: inline-block;

}

div.navigation { 

margin: 0 0 15px 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
display: inline;

}

button#navigation-buttons {

background-color: #000099;
border: 0px;
color: white;
padding: 10px 15px; 
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, not only do you want the buttons and the search field to occupy the same row, you also want the search field to take up all the remaining width?

If that is correct here is what you have to do:

1) Apply a table like layout but setting `.navigation` to `display:table` and adding two inner `.col` divs and setting them to `display:table-cell`

2) Set your first inner `.col` div to have a `width:0` and the other `width:100%`

3) Add `white-space:nowrap` to your `.navigation`

Working example:
http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/LGLzMw